# How to provide autocomplete street addresses functionality in django?

Tags: django, autocomplete, openstreetmap, geodjango

Is there any way to provide automatic street address suggestion when user tries to enter their address in the input box using so they start getting automatic address suggestions in django.

I was searching autocomplete light but could not find specially anything related to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've implemented this functionality with Google's Place Autocomplete. The sample code in the link is pretty spot on from memory.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform

Comment: Is it free to use this feature ?

Comment: There's a free tier which is includes something like 70,000 look-ups a month if this feature is all you use. I've been using that as well as drive time look-ups etc. for 12 months and it's been great https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/sheet/

Comment: Hi @vikram if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use python to make the requests yourself and implement some light javascript to fill your inputs:

This will return you a list of predictions based on the input address you supply. You just need an address and your API key to run the query, but note in my example I'm using the components/types parameters as well.

here's the documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/autocomplete

```
url = f'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=<address>&components=country:us&types=address&key=<your key>'
r = requests.get(url)
predictions = r.json()['predictions']

for p in predictions:
    print(p['description'])
    print('-----------------------')
```